# I have an unmountable SD Card: “Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE”

Tags: linux, sd-card

`dmesg` tells me that when I plug it in:

```
[      16:44] sd 6:0:0:4: [sdg] Spinning up disk...
[  +1.008912] ...................................................................................................not responding...
[      16:45] sd 6:0:0:4: [sdg] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  +0.000002] sd 6:0:0:4: [sdg] Sense Key : Not Ready [current]
[  +0.000001] sd 6:0:0:4: [sdg] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
```

Comment: Most likely the SD card itself is damaged. If you need data off of it, the best advice that can be given is to try to mount it using another reader. Sometimes other readers can deal with flaky media better than others.

Comment: You're totally right, thank you

Comment: In fact i have functionnal SD who does the same here, so it's a problem, sometimes

Comment: How did you connect the SD card to your computer? I ask because I have this one SSD that works perfectly in the laptop, connected over the internal SATA III bus, but I get the same "Read Capacity" failure when I connect it (to another computer) using a USB-2.5"-SATA-adapter cable. I use this external SATA-to-USB-cable a lot, with many different 2.5"-SATA drives, and so far only ONE has this issue, reproducibly. Hence, I suggest you try the SD card on another system, with other means of connection, before you decide that it's the SD card that is broken.

Comment: Um okay I have now an SD who does that, but always and on every devices, so it's a problem, anytime...